I don't understand why I type in "upm add markupsafe" it said errno
It showed me
~/WideeyedYawningStaffPRa$ upm add flask
--> poetry add flask
Skipping virtualenv creation, as specified in config file.
Using version ^3.0.3 for flask

Updating dependencies
Resolving dependencies... (0.2s)

Package operations: 7 installs, 0 updates, 0 removals

  - Installing markupsafe (2.1.5): Failed

  PermissionError

  [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/nix/store/rwxj49zghamyhy07b67yhiq64bmznvmm-python3-3.10.14/lib/python3.10/site-packages/markupsafe'

  at /nix/store/rwxj49zghamyhy07b67yhiq64bmznvmm-python3-3.10.14/lib/python3.10/pathlib.py:1175 in mkdir
      1171│         """
      1172│         Create a new directory at this given path.
      1173│         """
      1174│         try:
    → 1175│             self._accessor.mkdir(self, mode)
      1176│         except FileNotFoundError:
      1177│             if not parents or self.parent == self:
      1178│                 raise
      1179│             self.parent.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)

Cannot install markupsafe.

exit status 1
~/WideeyedYawningStaffPRa$ 

I tried removing it from pip but it is still not working. I want to use upm. Also I couldn't use flask and it showed
 * Serving Flask app 'main'
 * Debug mode: off
WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment. Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Running on all addresses (0.0.0.0)
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:8080
 * Running on http://172.31.196.3:8080
Press CTRL+C to quit
[2024-07-05 21:19:03,920] ERROR in app: Exception on / [GET]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/runner/WideeyedYawningStaffPRa/.pythonlibs/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1473, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/home/runner/WideeyedYawningStaffPRa/.pythonlibs/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 882, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/home/runner/WideeyedYawningStaffPRa/.pythonlibs/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 880, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/home/runner/WideeyedYawningStaffPRa/.pythonlibs/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 865, in dispatch_request
    return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**view_args)  # type: ignore[no-any-return]
  File "/home/runner/WideeyedYawningStaffPRa/main.py", line 11, in index
    return render_template('index.html')
  File "/home/runner/WideeyedYawningStaffPRa/.pythonlibs/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/templating.py", line 149, in render_template
    template = app.jinja_env.get_or_select_template(template_name_or_list)
  File "/home/runner/WideeyedYawningStaffPRa/.pythonlibs/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 1084, in get_or_select_template
    return self.get_template(template_name_or_list, parent, globals)
  File "/home/runner/WideeyedYawningStaffPRa/.pythonlibs/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 1013, in get_template
    return self._load_template(name, globals)
  File "/home/runner/WideeyedYawningStaffPRa/.pythonlibs/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 972, in _load_template
    template = self.loader.load(self, name, self.make_globals(globals))
  File "/home/runner/WideeyedYawningStaffPRa/.pythonlibs/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jinja2/loaders.py", line 126, in load
    source, filename, uptodate = self.get_source(environment, name)
  File "/home/runner/WideeyedYawningStaffPRa/.pythonlibs/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/templating.py", line 65, in get_source
    return self._get_source_fast(environment, template)
  File "/home/runner/WideeyedYawningStaffPRa/.pythonlibs/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/templating.py", line 99, in _get_source_fast
    raise TemplateNotFound(template)
jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound: index.html
172.31.196.3 - - [05/Jul/2024 21:19:03] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 -
[2024-07-05 21:19:04,052] ERROR in app: Exception on / [GET]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/runner/WideeyedYawningStaffPRa/.pythonlibs/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1473, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/home/runner/WideeyedYawningStaffPRa/.pythonlibs/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 882, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/home/runner/WideeyedYawningStaffPRa/.pythonlibs/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 880, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/home/runner/WideeyedYawningStaffPRa/.pythonlibs/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 865, in dispatch_request
    return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**view_args)  # type: ignore[no-any-return]
  File "/home/runner/WideeyedYawningStaffPRa/main.py", line 11, in index
    return render_template('index.html')
  File "/home/runner/WideeyedYawningStaffPRa/.pythonlibs/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/templating.py", line 149, in render_template
    template = app.jinja_env.get_or_select_template(template_name_or_list)
  File "/home/runner/WideeyedYawningStaffPRa/.pythonlibs/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 1084, in get_or_select_template
    return self.get_template(template_name_or_list, parent, globals)
  File "/home/runner/WideeyedYawningStaffPRa/.pythonlibs/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 1013, in get_template
    return self._load_template(name, globals)
  File "/home/runner/WideeyedYawningStaffPRa/.pythonlibs/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 972, in _load_template
    template = self.loader.load(self, name, self.make_globals(globals))
  File "/home/runner/WideeyedYawningStaffPRa/.pythonlibs/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jinja2/loaders.py", line 126, in load
    source, filename, uptodate = self.get_source(environment, name)
  File "/home/runner/WideeyedYawningStaffPRa/.pythonlibs/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/templating.py", line 65, in get_source
    return self._get_source_fast(environment, template)
  File "/home/runner/WideeyedYawningStaffPRa/.pythonlibs/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/templating.py", line 99, in _get_source_fast
    raise TemplateNotFound(template)
jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound: index.html
172.31.196.3 - - [05/Jul/2024 21:19:04] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 -

I'm using replit and every single time it can't connect to the website on the web view. The replit project on replit is the following: https://replit.com/@Nickys18/WideeyedYawningStaffPRa

You haven't sourced your virtualenv.

Those are two COMPLETELY separate problems.  The second is a file configuration issue -- you don't have your templates in the correct spot.
